# Как создать такую кнопку для подписки на группу ВК?

Tags: html, css, вконтакте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как создать такую кнопку для подписки на группу ВК с сайта?

Comment: Реально, 100%, легко!

Answer (score 3):

Реально, можно использовать виджет для сообществ([ссылка](https://vk.com/dev/Community?height=400&link=http%3A%2F%2Fvk.com%2Fpublic20003922&mode=3&no_cover=&oid=-20003922&wide=)), или второй вариант(если вы имели это ввиду)

```css
a {
  padding: 7px 16px 8px;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 12.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: none;
  background-color: #5181b8;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Подписаться на новости</a>
```

Comment: http://prntscr.com/i5j11o Просто кнопку сделать не дает ВК.

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi, не слыхал о том, чтобы можно было добавить лишь кнопку

Answer (score 3):

Технически можно всё, если вы не против парочки костыликов *(подписка не работает из за того, что код отображается в iframe)*.

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 174px !important;
  height: 30px !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: -98px;
  left: -13px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?152"></script>

<!-- VK Widget -->
<div id="container">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  VK.Widgets.Group('container', {
    mode: 1,
    no_cover: 1
  }, 20003922);
</script>
```

Comment: Можете объяснить подробнее что как надо делать? Ибо не выходит у меня.